# How to generate a simple popup box with simple html,css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup

I want to make a "contact form" popup in home page and I want that contact form should be in a light box.I am successfully displaying contact form in home page.But I am not getting light box background.I want to get a grey colour background behind the popup.Can any body help me?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", popupContact, true);

function popupContact() {
  setTimeout(popup, 3000);
}

function popup() {
  document.getElementById("popupBackground").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("popupBackground").style.width = 500 px;
  document.getElementById("popupBackground").style.height = 500 px;
  document.getElementById("contactPopup").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#popupBackground {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
}

contactPopup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popupBackground">
  <h1>this is 3987</h1>
</div>

<div id="contactPopup">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <form action="https://www.SnapHost.com/captcha/send.aspx" id="ContactUsCaptchaWebForm" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);" target="_top">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600">
      <tr>
        <td><b>Name*:</b></td>
        <td><input name="Name" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:350px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Phone number:</b></td>
        <td><input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" maxlength="43" style="width:350px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Email address*:</b></td>
        <td><input name="FromEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="60" style="width:350px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Comments and questions*:</b></td>
        <td><textarea name="Comments" rows="7" cols="40" style="width:350px;"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some more tags. For example Javascript, HTMl and form. Popup could be everything.

Comment: Syno i added some form elements ,please check

Comment: i meant the question tags ;)

Comment: Could you insert a js fiddle to your post? [How to insert a JS Fiddle to my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code had a couple of issues:

1)  It crashed because of a syntax error. Both times where you wrote `500 px` it should have been `"500px"`.

2) Your CSS rule for "contactPopup" was missing the `#` at the start to denote an element ID.

3) I'm not sure what the purpose of the separate "popupBackground" area was. It neither covered the area behind the popup, nor set it to a grey (or grey-ish) colour. And you don't need a separate background element anyway, you can just style the contactPopup element directly.

Here's a demo:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", popupContact, true);

function popupContact() {
  setTimeout(popup, 3000);
}

function popup() {
  document.getElementById("contactPopup").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#contactPopup {
  display: none;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #121212;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 350px;
}

table {
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contactPopup">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  <form action="https://www.SnapHost.com/captcha/send.aspx" id="ContactUsCaptchaWebForm" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);" target="_top">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name*</th>
        <td><input name="Name" type="text" maxlength="60" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <td><input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" maxlength="43" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Email address*</th>
        <td><input name="FromEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="60" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Comments and questions</th>
        <td><textarea name="Comments" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <table>
  </form>
</div>
```

You also had some deprecated element properties (e.g. on your table) which should be replaced by CSS, and some inline styles on your elements which should be replaced by entries in your main CSS block. I've also made the popup look a bit nicer in general with some rounded corners and softer font and colours.